# how to add default text to an input field in a form in WP

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, default-value

I am using a plugin in WP that generates a form based on input in the admin area. I have five fields that are set to url validation and such types appear in a form with a second field for optional link text, meaning if the user enters "http://stackoverflow.com" in the first field they have the option to type "Stackoverflow" in the second, and that is what will appear as the link text in the resulting listing in the web site directory. If the user leaves this field empty, the plugin will insert the url from the first field to fill it.

I have set these links to be styled as buttons, thus I need to control what appears on them so they are the right size. I want to add specific default text to each of these five fields, but I can't edit the form because it is generated dynamically.

One of these input fields for optional text is coded thus:

```
<input type="text" id="wpbdp-field-12-title" name="listingfields[12][1]" class="intextbox" value="" placeholder="">
```

Is there a way to use css or javascript or magic to insert text in the fields so it is submitted with the form? I want one, for example, to have the default text "Official Website" and other to read "Facebook" and so forth.

BTW, this field will be hidden by css so the form filler doesn't alter it. I just need these fields pre-filled to save labor by the admin.

Thank you, all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is no way to edit the input in the plugin you're using? If you wanted you can change it after the page load with the jQuery included in WP.

CODE

```
$(function() { 
    $('input#wpbdp-field-12-title').attr('value','your additional value text'); 
});
```

this is really not a full proof way of doing it as the plugin you use will change the ID of the field if you edit it in the future. Maybe look into using a different one or making your own php form.

EDIT

You could also have inputs with values predefined that are hidden and submitted along with it. I'm not sure if thats a possiblity for you.

Comment: Where would I put this code you recommend? It looks like what I need.

Comment: Put that code on the page where the form appears like this: `<script type="text/javascript"> code goes here </script>`. You can put that in  head or in the body right above the `</body>` tag, depending where you have access to inject it into your WP templates.

Comment: @Josh KG yep that's pretty much how, are you using a custom template?

Comment: It is a purchased template, but the template isn't the issue. Now I have also found that when viewing the page with the form that the form's html is not visible in code view. idk how that is possible. So, while I expect the above solution would work, it doesn't because of this. The form works in that you click a menu link to the form, then pick a category for your event, then click the continue button, which takes you to the main form, which is where these fields are displayed. When I view the source I see only the html for the first page for category selection. I've written to the programmer.

Comment: Finally got around to working on this again. My previous comment about the form code being not visible was in error, but the suggested code isn't working. It shows up in the head area, but not working. One of the fields I want to have filled is coded thus: 
`<input type="text" id="wpbdp-field-10-title" name="listingfields[10][1]" class="intextbox" value="" placeholder="">` 
and for it's line in the script I wrote this: 
`$(function() { 
    $('input#wpbdp-field-10-title').attr('value','Buy Tickets'); 
});` Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The whole of my inserted script is this: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
    $('input#wpbdp-field-10-title').attr('value','Buy Tickets'); 
});

$(function() { 
    $('input#wpbdp-field-5-title').attr('value','Official Website'); 
});

$(function() { 
    $('input#wpbdp-field-11-title').attr('value','Facebook'); 
});

$(function() { 
    $('input#wpbdp-field-12-title').attr('value','Twitter'); 
});

$(function() { 
    $('input#wpbdp-field-17-title').attr('value','Our Video'); 
});

</script>`

Comment: If anyone can help with getting this to work it would be fantastic. It's very important to get this resolved.

Comment: The page it is needed for is at [HERE](http://nextinthewest.com/next-in-the-west-calendar/?action=submitlisting)